Написание декораторов с дополнительной обёрткой и без неё
Есть два декоратора, первый без дополнительной функции, в качестве параметров принимает сразу и функцию, которой мы добавляем дополнительный функционал, и аргументы этой же функции:
def test(*args): #Наша функция, тест, которая будет принимать произвольное количество параметров.
    print(*args)

def call_start_end(func, *args):
    print('Начало теста')
    func(*args)
    print('Конец теста')

call_start_end(test, 'Тестируем', 'Ещё не закончили', '...')
# Вывод :
# Начало теста
# Тестируем, Ещё не закончили, ...
# Конец теста

Второй декоратор уже использует дополнительную функцию, чтобы обернуть обёртку:
def test(*args):
    print(*args)

def prewrapper(func): #Обёртка для обёртки, которая принимает функцию.
    def call_start_end(*args): # Сама обёртка, которая принимает аргументы для функции, функционал которой мы расширяем.
        print('Начало теста')
        func(*args) 
        print('Конец теста')
    return call_start_end

prewrapper(test)('Тестируем', 'Ещё не закончили', '...')
# Вывод:
# Начало теста
# Тестируем Ещё не закончили ...
# Конец теста

Так вот буду благодарен, если объясните зачем оборачивать обертку еще одной оберткой, в которую мы отдельно передаем функцию, вместо того, чтобы как в первом примере декоратора, не передавать их в одну обёртку? Мне кажется отчасти декораторы сложны для понимания именно из-за этого момента, сразу так и не ясно зачем дополнительно оборачивать в ещё одну обёртку. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Ответ простой - чтобы использовать эти декораторы не "вручную", а именно как декораторы - задекорировав через @ некоторые функции этим декоратором.
@call_start_end
def test(*args): #Наша функция, тест, которая будет принимать произвольное количество параметров.
    print(*args)

test('Тестируем', 'Ещё не закончили', '...')

Ошибка!

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

@prewrapper
def test(*args):
    print(*args)
    
test('Тестируем', 'Ещё не закончили', '...')

Всё работает как задумано.
Начало теста
Тестируем Ещё не закончили ...
Конец теста

При использовании декораторов через @ вы можете передать в декоратор и аргументы и функцию, но только по отдельности: декоратору - функцию, самой функции - аргументы. Нет единого вызова, чтобы передать сразу всё. А если вы захотите, чтобы ещё и у самого декоратора были какие-то аргументы, которые ему самому можно передать, то вам придётся писать уже целых два враппера:

внешний враппер будет принимать параметры декоратора
внутренний будет принимать ссылку на функцию
функция внутри этих двух врапперов уже будет выполнять собственно нужный вам функционал

Поэтому всё выглядит внешне так сложно, но если разобраться, то всё довольно логично и понятно зачем и почему так всё сделано.
Вообще смысл декораторов в том, что вы никак не меняете основной код, вы по-прежнему вызываете вашу функцию, как будто ничего не изменилось:
test('Тестируем', 'Ещё не закончили', '...')

Вы просто добавили некий модификатор к описанию функции и таким образом меняете её поведение нужным образом, добавляя к нему некий функционал. Что довольно удобно - у вас одна точка изменения, там же, где находится описание самой функции. Вы можете даже применять к функции несколько декораторов по очереди, и это будет выглядеть довольно логично и понятно.

Без вашего подробного разъяснения купил бы ещё дней пять, премного благодарю)
